# Combobox "ArgumentOutOfRangeException" at "ComboBox.ObjectCollection.cs"

Tags: c#, exception, combobox

i have a project where i use multiple comboboxes with dynamic lists inside them.
so i made a method for search inside the comboboxes by clicking in the combobox to drop it down and then typing the word i am looking for in text area of the combobox and list is changing with each character i type.
the problem i am facing is when there is no match for the word i am looking for, the list in the combobox became empty and as soon as i click outside the combobox i get a "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" exception in "ComboBox.ObjectCollection.cs".
to test the problem here is a test project using the same methods and events i use in my original project: https://github.com/Abdourealcf/ComboboxSearch
to replicate the error just click on the combobox and type anything like "wwwwww" and imediately click outside the combobox.
here is a video for more details: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1waCJMmLm7ByWdc3_WntOW8TMI_TjRsq2/view?usp=sharing
Please help me.
i have no clue what is causing the exception!
here is the stack trace:

> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.this[int].get(int index) Line 233   C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.SelectedItem.get() Line 1054 C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.Text.get() Line 1246 C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 3737   C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 3867    C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 67 C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 117  C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, Interop.User32.WM msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Line 370 C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.Primitives.dll!Interop.User32.SendMessageW(IHandle hWnd, Interop.User32.WM Msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Line 23713 C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessage(System.IntPtr hWnd, ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 9918  C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 11831  C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 13045    C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 1504   C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 2090    C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 6632    C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 67 C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 117  C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, Interop.User32.WM msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Line 370 C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 516  C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ComboBoxChildNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) Line 62    C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, Interop.User32.WM msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Line 370 C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.Interop.Mso.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.UIntPtr dwComponentID, Interop.Mso.msoloop uReason, void* pvLoopData) Line 346  C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Interop.Mso.msoloop reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 1117  C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Interop.Mso.msoloop reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) Line 981    C#
> [Exception] System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) Line 1188 C#
> [Exception] ComboboxSearch.dll!ComboboxSearch.Program.Main() Line 14    C#
> System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, Interop.User32.WM msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Line 381 C#

Comment: You will need to either examine your stack trace or step through the code to determine which line of your code is causing the exception. My guess is you are trying to retrieve an item from the combobox even when it is empty.

Comment: thank you for your comment
i don't think the exception is caused by any events or methods in my code did you try to duplicate the error?
i added the stack trace for more details.

Comment: I think i figured out the cause of the problem.
As i understand there is an event that fires in "ComboBox.cs" when the combobox dropdown closes "OnDropDownClosed", that event compares the text i typed with the elements in the list and when it finds a match it auto-selects that match. and sins the list is empty it throws "ArgumentOutOfRangeException". as i said this is not caused by my code.
is there any work around to prevent the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around i did this:

```
string old_txt; 
private void ComboBox1_DropDownClosed(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
if (comboBox1.Items.Count<=0) 
{ 
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1; 
comboBox1.Text = old_txt ; 
comboBox1.SelectionStart = comboBox1.Text.Length; 
} 
}
```

and in my `comboBox1_KeyUp` event i added: `old_txt = comboBox1.Text;`
I know its ugly but it does fix the problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).